# SWReveal TableViewController - how to launch to different ViewControllers?

Tags: swift, tableview, viewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using the SWReveal slide out menuing system.
The menu is generated from an array, and all works fine. E.g.

```
arrayOfCellData = [cellData(cell : 1, text : "Angles", image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Angles.png")),
                   cellData(cell : 2, text : "Area", image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Area.png")),
```

When I tap on a particular menu option I want to segue to a different ViewController. Here is the code that I have been using which doesn't work.
The idea that Row 1 invokes segue A and 2 segue B...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if(indexPath.row == 1 ){
        let vc: AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "A")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "A", sender: self)
        self.show(vc as! A, sender: vc)
        NSLog("A")
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 2 ){
        let vc: AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "B", sender: self)
        self.show(vc as! B, sender: vc)
        NSLog("B")
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = " "
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem


    if segue.identifier == "A", let nextScene = segue.destination as? A {
        nextScene.categoryCounter = 1
    }
    if segue.identifier == "B", let nextScene = segue.destination as? B {
        nextScene.categoryCounter = 2
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController` as root controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SWRevealViewController it is best to not use segues in storyboard and instead contract your reveal view controller programmatically. Try this, in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method add the following to your code.

```
// Here I get the view controllers I am interested in
let frontStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboard", bundle: .main)
let frontVC = frontStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

let rearStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourOtherStoryboard", bundle: .main)
let rearVC = rearStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

// Construct the SWRevealViewController with your view controllers
if let revealVC = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearVC, frontViewController: frontVC) {
    revealVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve // Set segue transition
    present(revealVC, animated: true, completion: nil) // Segue to view controller
}
```

Comment: What links do I need between the SWReveal TableView menu and the pages they are calling? Standard Segue links but without the segue code? Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean links? You just need to know what option was pressed, which you will know from the `indexPath.row` value. From there you will get the proper view controllers to load into your `SWRevealViewController` then present ("segue", same thing) that `SWRevealViewController`.